# Keras Convolutional layer with different filter sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to use Keras and TensorFlow to create [this](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/11842615/25828679/df9dc5c6-3451-11e7-9792-c8fa32dd920f.png) CNN architecture as described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.03820.pdf). [This example](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6547#issuecomment-302987973) shows a way of doing so using a Merge layer, which was removed from Keras. How do I replicate this CNN architecture with a newer version of Keras?

Answer (score 0):

You need `tf.keras.layers.Concatenate`:

```
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name='img')
conv_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu')(input_layer)
conv_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(input_layer)
conv_merged = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([conv_1, conv_2])
```